# Exception trying to geocode an address

Tags: ios, swift

I've got the following code which results in an exception and I don't know why. Once the exception is hit in XCode I can't continue to find out what the exception is - what I mean is normally you can continue execution in XCode and you can examine the call stack to see what the reason for the exception is, but in this case when I click the Continue Program Execution button it just continually sticks at the particular line in the screenshot.

```
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
geoCoder.geocodeAddressString("Infinite Loop,Cupertino,California", completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    print("WTF")
} as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

[image]

The project is linked with the MapKit framework.

Comment: Try pressing "continue" for a couple of times. You may then loose the breakpoint (which does not matter as you know already where it  happens) but you have good chances to see in the log which type of exception that is. 

Then go from there or add the stacktrace etc. to your question.

Comment: I've tried clicking continue dozens of times, it doesn't move beyond that line, so I can't get a useful stacktrace.

Comment: See what happens when you set "Break on All Exceptions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is all wrong. You shouldn't be trying to force-cast anything. Assuming Swift 3 you need:

```
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
geoCoder.geocodeAddressString("Infinite Loop,Cupertino,California", completionHandler: { (placemark: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
    // do stuff
})
```

or even more simply:

```
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
geoCoder.geocodeAddressString("Infinite Loop,Cupertino,California") { (placemark: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: That's the problem with Swift constantly evolving, I copied/pasted the code from a tutorial and it was XCode itself that added "as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler" andXCode didn't notice that NSError should now be Error

Comment: Using `Error` is for Swift 3. Use `NSError` for Swift 2.

Comment: Yes I know, thanks. But its easy to miss that sort of thing when copying/pasting code and I expected XCode itself ought to have noticed.

Comment: Your first problem is that your are copying and pasting code.  You should really be typing it all out, that's how you learn.